# Unable to login to Jenkins after ADFS certificate update

Tags: security, authentication, jenkins, saml-2.0, adfs

My jenkins was integrated with ADFS for SSO and we were able to login to Jenkins.

However, the ADFS SSL certificate was updated post which we are not getting the Jenkins login page. It instead shows the https://jenkins-host:port/SamlLogout page.

ADFS team has sent us their updated metadata file called "FederationMetadata.xml".

However, now that we are not able to login to Jenkins I'm not aware of the procedure to update the metadata for ADFS SAML 2.0 integration.

Can someone please suggest what the options and the best price to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you should be doing.

1. login to your Jenkins server , do a terminal login.
2. Locate the jenkins installation folder , you should see the jenkins config file

> By default Jenkins home directory ( JENKINS_HOME ) is set to ~/.jenkins , this is the location where you can find your Jenkins XML config file

3. Open the file in an editor and replace the Idp Metadata section with the new contents of the FederationMetadata.xml file and save the file
4. Restart Jenkins

Comment: after replacing the data between ldp Metadata section the issue persists.

Comment: error logs:
org.pac4j.saml.metadata.SAML2ServiceProviderMetadataResolver resolve
WARNING: Could not construct the directory structure for SP metadata /app/Jenkins/jenkins_home/saml-sp-metadata.xml
org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature checkSignatureValue
WARNING: Signature verification failed.
org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator validateSamlSSOResponse
SEVERE: Current assertion validation failed, continue with the next one
org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Signature is not trusted

Comment: org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Signature is not trusted
        at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.validateSignature(SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.java:689)

Later the below is printed in the output.

Caused by: org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: No valid subject assertion found in response
        at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.validateSamlSSOResponse(SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.java:313

Comment: The ADFS Metadata contents were copied between <xml></xml> tags in the below from the configuration:

    <idpMetadataConfiguration>
      <xml></xml>
      <url></url>
      <period>0</period>
    </idpMetadataConfiguration>

Note: after the restarting Jenkins and trying to login then; the copied Metadata disappears from the config.xml which I had copied manually.

Comment: Sure , will try to respond back later today with some inputs

Answer (score 0):

Stop jenkins.
Inside jenkins home, there is a file `saml-idp-metadata.xml`
Copy content of `FederationMetadata.xml` and paste in to this file.
Start jenkins.